# merge sort in Pharo

Tags: pharo

Sorry for my poor english.
So, i have a problem with my merge sort.
This is the merge part :

```
fusion: nTableau debut: deb1 fin1: fin1 fin2: fin2

| deb2 compt1 compt2 i t |

t := #().
deb2 := fin1 + 1.
compt1 := deb1.
compt2 := deb2.
i:= deb1.

(i to: fin1) do: [ t at:(i-deb1) put: (nTableau at:i) ].

i := deb1.
i to: deb1 do: [
    (compt1 = deb2) ifTrue: [  ]
    ifFalse:  [ compt2 =(fin2 +1)ifTrue: [ nTableau at:i put: (t at: compt1-deb1). compt1 := compt1+1 ] ];
    ifFalse: [ (t at: (compt1-deb1) < nTableau at: compt2) ifTrue: [ nTableau at:i put: (t at:(compt1 - deb1)). compt1 := compt1 +1 ]  ];
    ifFalse: [ nTableau at:i put: (nTableau at:compt2) ]
      ]
```

And this is my sort part that do recursivity :

tri

```
| trier milieu |
trier := nil.
trier := [ :tab :deb :fin |
                [ deb := (taille/taille). fin = taille. tab := tableau ].
                [ milieu := ( deb + fin ) //                    
                                    (deb ~= fin) ifTrue: [ 
                                        trier value: tab value: deb value: milieu.
                                        trier value: tab value: milieu+1 value: fin. 
                                        fusion: tab deb: debut fin1: milieu fin2: fin.
                               ]
     ]
```

I have the problem on the sort part. Please help me.

Comment: So, what's "the problem"?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have misunderstood what #ifTrue:ifFalse: and that family of messages do.

They are not syntactic constructions, but messages sent to objects and affected by ; as a cascade.

In your example, you have

```
i to: deb1 do: [
    condition 
     ifTrue: [  ]
     ifFalse: [ condition2 ifTrue: [ actions ] ];
     ifFalse: [ condition3 ifTrue: [ other actions ];
     ifFalse: [ an action more ]
```

but that sends to the same boolean condition the first ifTrue:ifFalse: (which, by the way, is the same that just putting ifFalse: because the empty block in the ifTrue: part). And after, ifFalse: again, two more times, to the same object (because that is what the ; means). The condition is not re-evaluated, so if the first time it was true, nothing is done and if it was false, the three bocks of action will be performed.
It is equivalent to have only one ifFalse, concatenating all the actions inside the blocks.
...and I don´t think that is what you intended.

Also, you had before that

```
i := deb1.
i to: deb1 do: [ ... ]
```

and there you use the same value, doing deb1 to: deb1.
(Does that even run? I thought that the block requires an argument)

Comment: Hello sir, i rectifiy it. That's i to: fin2 do: [...]. I have understood what you said. i have modified the code many times and that not run yet. Propose me a good method (function) that do the merge please. Thanks

Comment: No, sorry. I will not do homework for others. I don't remember the algorithm by heart and searching for it to translate (without good reason) to Smalltalk, makes no sense to me as exercise